# How to implement fancy scroll bar for multiline textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, scrollbar

I want to implement a fancy scroll bar for a multiline textbox like the picture below:

[image: Standard scroll bar and fancy scroll bar]

Any ideas for that fancy scroll bar?

P/S: I want vb.net solution.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Is that inappropriate for user to ask specific solution in vb.net?

Comment: @Gens: He has a VB.Net tag on the question, that should be enough.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I have seen this question before, only C# answer being offered. And this time the same question with a bounty, so I guess he wants specific answer in vb.net.

Comment: @Dee Jay: You have a VB.Net tag, you do not have to also say you want it in VB.Net in your question. I removed those superfluous details from your question to improve its readability. However, at your request I will make no more edits.

Comment: Why do you want to make this custom scrollbar? It's better to respect the default GUI elements. I could understand it if you wanted to do this in a Flash application, a website or a game maybe.

Comment: @Midas: I need custom scroll bar to match my main winform theme. For your info, my winform also without standard title bar and I use the fancy one. Secondly, only custom scroll bar can guarantee the layout consistency for all versions of windows.

Comment: Just making a bad GUI "worser" - stick to standard, it is always easier for the users

Comment: @TFD: Bad "GUI"? You mean my sample fancy scroll bar picture? Well the actual scroll bar in my application will be much better in design and even easier for the users.

Comment: @TFD Whts wrong? .. try some new if it clicks that will become standard.. +1 vote for new idea

Comment: Can the scroll bar part be another control? I mean do you need the listbox and the scrollbar to be one control, or is it ok if the scrollbar is actually implemented by another class?

Comment: @Simon Mourier: thanks for your code. Your code is very good but as I eager to learn more, do you have code for scroll bar that integrated with a particular control like multiline textbox or listbox? Please share with us.

Comment: @Dee Jay - nope, I don't have that because it's much more complex. The Windows OS has never had good support for integrated custom draw scrollbars, hence my original question, and the associated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fancy scroll bar can be implemented as another control (your image actually looks like that), here is the code of a ListBox that supports custom scrolling:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class CustomScrollListBox
    Inherits ListBox

    Public Sub Scroll(ByVal percentage As Single)
        If (percentage < 0.0!) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException(Nothing, "percentage")
        End If

        ' Sends the scroll / set position Windows message
        Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115
        Const SB_THUMBPOSITION As Integer = 4
        Dim wp As Integer = CInt(((percentage * MyBase.Items.Count) * 65536.0!)) + SB_THUMBPOSITION
        CustomScrollListBox.SendMessage(MyBase.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, New IntPtr(wp), IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            ' Removes the vertical scroll window style
            Dim p As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            Const WS_VSCROLL As Integer = &H200000
            p.Style = (p.Style And -WS_VSCROLL)
            Return p
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

And here is a sample form that uses it. I have implemented the custom scroller as a standard Trackbar (trackBar1) for the example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private trackBar As TrackBar
    Private listBox As CustomScrollListBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        ' initialize some listbox props
        listBox = New CustomScrollListBox
        listBox.Location = New Point(&H19, 210)
        listBox.Name = "listBox2"
        listBox.Size = New Size((&H17D - Me.TrackBar1.Width), &HAD)
        listBox.TabIndex = 1
        MyBase.Controls.Add(listBox)

       ' add some items
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 100 - 1
            listBox.Items.Add(("item" & i))
        Next i

    End Sub


    Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
        ' compute trackbar's position as a percentage
        listBox.Scroll(CSng(TrackBar1.Maximum - TrackBar1.Value) / TrackBar1.Maximum - TrackBar1.Minimum)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4):

This code is very chunky and frustrating to work with but it's working

> This is a fully drawn GDI+ custom
>   scrollbar control class. All of its
>   drawing methods are overrideable,
>   allowing developers to paint it
>   however they choose.
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/corescrollbar.aspx